# Devise redirecting to different resource when using force_ssl

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have `force_ssl`enabled for my entire application and am using Devise for authentication. However in production when I try and access an http devise-path e.g., `http://domain.com/users/sign_in`, then I am redirected to the https version of the path but with a different resource e.g., `https://domain.com/admins/sign_in`.

This seems to be dependent on the order the resources are given in routes.rb. So for instance if I have:

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins
```

Then accessing `http://domain.com/admins/sign_in`will redirect to `https://domain.com/users/sign_in`, whereas `http://domain.com/users/sign_in`will maintain the correct resource and redirect to `https://domain.com/users/sign_in`.

If I change the order of the resources in routes.rb, then the opposite is true.

I have implemented a very slightly customized version of `force_ssl`in my application controller in order to be able to later specify some controller actions as exceptions.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
include ApplicationHelper
protect_from_forgery

#Re-implement force_ssl to allow override in controllers
def self.force_ssl(options = {})
 host = options.delete(:host)
 before_filter(options) do
  if !request.ssl? && !Rails.env.development? && !(respond_to?(:allow_http?) && allow_http?)
    redirect_options = {:protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently}
    redirect_options.merge!(:host => host) if host
    redirect_options.merge!(:params => request.query_parameters)
    redirect_to redirect_options
  end
 end
end

force_ssl
end
```

How can I ensure that the devise resource is maintained in the re-direct from http to https?

Thanks